# How to change column to row names in a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, lapply

I have a list of dataframes and I want change one column into rownames because I need to transpose each dataframe.

With some dummy data, here is the code I am using:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
y <- c(1:5)
z <- c(6:10)

df1 <- data.frame("Row One"=x, "Row Two"=y)
df2 <- data.frame("Row One"=x, "Row Two"=z)
dfList <- list(df1,df2)
```

I tried with lapply, no luck.

```
dfList <- lapply(dfList, column_to_rownames("Row One"))
```

Didn't work with a for loop either.

```
for(i in length(dfList)){
  dfList[i] <- column_to_rownames(dfList[i], "Row One") 
}
```

Based on the error message, I tried adding as.data.frame to the list element, which didn't work either.

```
for(i in length(dfList)){
      dfList[i] <- column_to_rownames(as.data.frame(dfList[i], "Row One")) 
    }
```

Strange thing about the last one is the error said "Can't find column `Row One` in `.data`."

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your approach with `lapply()` is correct. The only error you made is to use a space in the column names. That way R internally puts a dot where you see the space!

To cite your example, if you check the column names of `df1` you see that

```
> colnames(df1)
[1] "Row.One" "Row.Two"
```

That is one reason your `lapply()` command didn't work out. The other error was that you didn't specify the data in the `column_to_rownames()` command, i.e. `lapply(dfList, column_to_rownames("Row One"))` is wrong but `lapply(dfList, function(x) column_to_rownames(x, var = "Row One"))` is correct.

With these corrections, the code that works is

```
dfList <- lapply(dfList, function(x) column_to_rownames(x, var = "Row.One"))
```

Note, however, that now you got the `data.frame`s

```
> dfList
[[1]]
  Row.Two
A       1
B       2
C       3
D       4
E       5

[[2]]
  Row.Two
A       6
B       7
C       8
D       9
E      10
```

That is, you eliminated the first column and assigned it as rownames. If you want to *keep* the first column **and** set the rownames, you could do

```
dfList2 <- lapply(dfList, function(x){rownames(x) <- x[,1]; x})
```

with the output

```
> dfList2
[[1]]
  Row.One Row.Two
A       A       1
B       B       2
C       C       3
D       D       4
E       E       5

[[2]]
  Row.One Row.Two
A       A       6
B       B       7
C       C       8
D       D       9
E       E      10
```